# Cloudflare .js Challenge vs Google Invisible reCaptcha

Tags: cloudflare, invisible-recaptcha

I have to block all bots (except google bot) to my site. 
I was recommended both Cloudflare .js challenge and Google Invisible ReCaptcha. 
I use them both at the same time and stopped the bots, but now it takes too long to reach the site. I will now choose only one of them. 
Which one is better in your opinion? Cloudflare or Google?